# Is there any way to use Booleanbuilder with Query method?

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

Hi I'm currently using Query method to get my result. the design of my app is as below.

**Member Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long mno;

    private String name;

    private String phone;

}
```

**MemberImage Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString(exclude="member")
public class MemberImage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long inum;

    private String uuid;

    private String imgName;

    private String path;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Member member;
}
```

and the query method that I'm using

**MemberRepository.java**

```java
    @Query("select m, mi, count(mi) from Member m"+ " left outer join MemberImage mi on mi.member=m group by m")
    Page<Object[]> getListPage(Pageable pageable);
```

**PageRequestDTO.java**

```java
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PageRequestDTO {

    private int page;
    private int size;
    private String type;
    private String keyword;


    public PageRequestDTO(){
        this.page = 1;
        this.size = 10;
    }

    public Pageable getPageable(Sort sort){

        return PageRequest.of(page -1, size, sort);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a search operation with Booleanbuilder like below

```java
 private BooleanBuilder getSearch(PageRequestDTO requestDTO){

        String type = requestDTO.getType();

        BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();



        String keyword = requestDTO.getKeyword();

        BooleanExpression expression = qMember.mno.gt(0L);

        booleanBuilder.and(expression);

        if(type == null || type.trim().length() == 0){
            return booleanBuilder;
        }

        BooleanBuilder conditionBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();

        if(type.contains("n")){
            conditionBuilder.or(qMember.name.contains(keyword));
        }
        if(type.contains("p")){
            conditionBuilder.or(qMember.phone.contains(keyword));
        }

        booleanBuilder.and(conditionBuilder);



        return booleanBuilder;
    }
```

I want the results with Page<Object[]> with the terms of booleanBuilder that I coded. Is there any way to get this result?
I tried memberRepository.getListPage(booleanBuilder,pageable) and see if I can get the right results, but it didn't. Any suggestions?